# How can I reset form after render template and hide modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-forms

I have a django view and I render a template like this:

```
 return render(request, 'submission/submit_url.html',
                                      {'form': form, 'has_modal_info': 1})
```

On my template (submit_url), I get that variable **"has_modal_info"** and depending on the value (0 or 1) I decide to call or not my modal:

```
<!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            {% if has_modal_info %}
                {% include 'submission/finishing_modal.html' %}
                <script>
                    var finishing_modal = $('#end-submission-modal');
                    finishing_modal.modal();
                </script>
                <script>
                    finishing_modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e){
                        var id_url_form = $('#id_url_form');
                        id_url_form[0].reset();
                        console.log("Your event works!");
                    });
                </script>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The form I'm trying to reset:

```
<form id="id_url_form" action="{% url 'pages.submission.views.submit_url' %}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="url_form">
```

After rendering and submitting the form, I call my modal and try to "hook" the **hidden** event by resetting my form on that event for clearing all fields, but it doesn't work.
Tried Jquery trigger and a lot of possibilities but no success.
My opinion is that this happens because django render is Hooked my my modal call and can't clear the form, but I have no idea how to work this around.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
id_url_form.each(function(){  
   $(this).val('')
}
```

Comment: thx for the example, couldn't make it work...
my solution until now is to clear the fields "by force"

    `$('#element).val('').change();`